# Centos 7.1 still using outdate kernel 3.10 how to upgrade to kernel 4.0

Tags: centos, kernel

I'd like to upgrade my Centos 7.1 kernel from 3.10 to 4.0
[image: Centos 7.1 kernel 3.10]

i did successfully in Ubuntu 15.04 using Linux  4.0.1-040001-generic
[image: Ubuntu 15.04 kernel 4.01]

even though i updated it manually it's works fine

so please could anyone tell me how to upgrade Centos 7.1 Kernel to 4.0

Comment: CentOS is based directly on Red Hat Enterprise, which has its legit. reasons for still being on kernel 3.10, to be honest if I were you, if you want a newer kernel, go with a distro that already uses a much newer kernel by default, like something in the 'Arch' family, for example. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: well i did successfully upgrade my kernel as the answer bellow, for some reason i really need newer kernel, especially in my experience using kernel 4.0 is much more stable and no crash or hang on nvidia driver

Comment: I am on a Debian box on kernel 3.16, also using the nvidia proprietary drivers, if I get a chance I want to try running a system based on the newest kernel(4.x series) to see what differences(if any) would exist on my specific platform.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could upgrade the kernel via [elrepo](http://elrepo.org/).

```
rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-7.0-2.el7.elrepo.noarch.rpm (external link)
yum install --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel kernel-ml
```

You can also install the updated firmware and headers

```
yum install --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel kernel-ml-{firmware,headers,devel}
```

You'll probably need to remove the `kernel-firmware` first:

```
yum remove kernel-{firmware,headers,devel}
```

Comment: your answer helped me out ... BTW, http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml says -firmware does not need to be installed.